# Do all objects have a __qualname__ attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, introspection

I was doing some introspection on pandas objects when I encountered an error for `pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer`.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__) say:

> `definition.__qualname__`
>
> The qualified name of the class, function, method, descriptor, or
>   generator instance.

I'm wondering if all objects are expected to have `__qualname__` (assuming Python 3.3+) and if not, what objects are those.

Comment: No, the docs are explicitly telling *which* types of objects have that attribute: "The qualified name of the class, function, method, descriptor, or generator instance."

Answer (score 1):

According to [PEP3155](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) `__qualname__` was introduced on `class` and `function` objects.

Now, we need to remember that in Python *everything* is an object. Functions are objects. Classes are objects! And here we don't mean "instances of classes" are objects, but the classes themselves are objects.

Example:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __init__(self, a): self.a = a
...
>>> c = C(2)
>>> type(c)
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> hasattr(c, '__qualname__')
False
>>> hasattr(C, '__qualname__')
True
>>> C.__qualname__
'C'
```

So the class `C` has `__qualname__` but instances of this class do not have it. You can retrieve it with an indirection, however: `c.__class__.__qualname__` (small `c`)

Similarly for functions:

```
>>> def f(b): print(b)
...
>>> hasattr(f, '__qualname__')
True
>>> f.__qualname__
'f'
```

If you nest classes and functions, their `__qualname__` will indicate this definition hierarchy. See [What is qualname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58110139/786559)